# VBA Insert value in a empty cell in a new row

Tags: vba, excel

Already googled like 3 or 4 hours but couldn't find anything that is working.

What I want to have and what is already done:

```
If meinWert > 16000000 And meinWert < 20000000 Then
        Sheets("Aufträge").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Date
        Sheets("Aufträge").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = meinWert
```

meinWert is avalue from a Scanner input which is an order number. The code above is a part of something bigger that is already running. The result of the code above is this:
[image]

And for each order there are some items (from 1 to like 10 items), now I need a code that jumps into row "C" and insert the item code. Like I said, there are more then one items per order and so each of this items (input via scanner) should be listed on the same line as the right order number like this:
[image]

I thought about smth. like this `Sheets("Aufträge").Cells(Target.Row, 255).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)` but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what you have, you should figure out the row once, and then use this row to insert all of the values into it:

```
Dim row As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim itemCount As Integer
Dim bolMoreItems As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("Aufträge")

If meinWert > 16000000 And meinWert < 20000000 Then
    bolMoreItems = True
    row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
    ws.Cells(row, 1) = Date
    ws.Cells(row, 2) = "test"

    itemCount = 1 'this isn't really needed except as a count to how many items there are.

    While bolMoreItems = True
        ws.Cells(row, 2 + itemCount) = "value" & itemCount 'instead of "value" & itemCount, put in whatever the value is.
         If there_are_no_more_items Then 'need some check to determine if there are more items....
             bolMoreItems = False
         End If

         itemCount = itemCount + 1

    Wend

End If
```

I've used a variable for the sheet to make it easier to read and code.  Obviously, I don't know how many items there are, so you'd need to do something to figure it out.  I also don't know what you're trying to insert into the new columns so leave this to you.

By the way, this wasn't working for you because `Target` is a keyword.  I don't know what the rest of your code is doing, but this is used in Event Handlers to specify the cell that triggered the event.  You likely have nothing like this, so this wouldn't work.  You could do something like this, but instead it would look like:

```
 Sheets("Aufträge").Cells(Sheets("Aufträge").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 255) _
                 .End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
```

where the `_` is simply continuing the statement on the next line.  This ends up not being clear what you are trying to do and is not the best solution anyways.

Comment: Never thought about that, looks great but there is another problem. I never know the exact value of items which will be inserted and each item will be scanned one after one.
So I thought about you scan the order number first and them all itmes needed, after that the order number will be scanned again to finish this line and go to the next one.
Also there is another sheet in which all of these items are listed with description and another makro will add each item which will be scanned so we are able to have an overview of the stock.

Comment: I'll update for this, but you will need SOME way of determining when the input is done....

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look at monday at work, maybe I need to post the whole script but first I will try to solve it by my self.